# Where is the original Fabergé egg in Octopussy?

Tags: james-bond, octopussy

In **[Octopussy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octopussy)**, James accompanies Fanning to the auction where Fabergé egg, The Property of a Lady, is being auctioned. He had the fake one and then he switched it with the one being auctioned, which is supposed to be original.

Later in the movie, Magda took it from James by seducing him and then he is kidnapped by Kamal. When Orlov, a Soviet general, arrives at Monsoon Palace, he says that it's a fake one and destroys it.

So, where is the original one? Is it mentioned in the movie or the book it is based on?

Comment: Though it's been a while, I think you got it wrong somewhere... I think Orlov crushes the *real* one that had the bug in it and that Magda recovered, *thinking* it's fake. (And the other one *is* fake, so it doesn't really matter what happened to it.) I admit it's all very confusing, though.

Comment: It's kinda, isn't it? M says, *there is the real thing. It's being auctioned at Sotheby's this afternoon.* So the one that was auctioned was original.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's been a while, but as far as I know, *the chain of events is this one* (quoted from an [entire thread](http://www.ajb007.co.uk/topic/41908/octopussy-why-did-orlov-destroy-the-real-egg/) about this confusing matter in a James Bond forum and corroborated by IMDb [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086034/faq#.2.1.11), which also explains the matter further [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086034/faq#.2.1.10)):

> 1. 009 managed to steal a replica of the Faberge egg and bring it to the British embassy
> 2. Bond "borrows" the replica and takes it to the Christie's auction
> 3. Bond replaces the real Christie's egg with the replica
> 4. Bond hands over the real Christie's egg to Mi6
> 5. The real egg gets prepared by Q with the bug transmitter
> 6. Bond takes the real but bugged egg to India and teases Kamal with it during the backgammon game
> 7. **Magda steals the real bugged egg and hands it over to Kamal** who has now 2 eggs
> 8. **Kamal hands the egg over to Orlov who destroys it** saying that this replica caused so much trouble. (You can see that **he's destroying the real egg** because the the transmitter falls off then - so he's not destroying the replica).

So in the end, the *fake* egg, believed to be the *real* one, is heading back to Moscow while the *real* egg is destroyed, like so many other priceless artifacts foolishly handed over to 007 along the years. ;)

Comment: Wish I could give +1 more for the last line. ;-)

Comment: Although *She lives on a floating palace in Delhi* is incorrect. This floating palace is in Udaipur.